# Batch error well assigning Variables?

Tags: batch-file

Alright, I used to be good at this but I haven't done it in a while so I'm a little rusty. Well I was making a little program I ran across an error, a variable would not set. So I messed with it and took out everything not relative to that variable but I could not get it to work! To demonstrate my problem I came up with this:

```
@echo off
:V
set /p V = "What is V? "
echo V is %V%.
goto V
```

Simple right? Here's how it should work in theory:

```
What is V? V
V is V.
What is V? _
```

Obviously, that's how it should work. Instead it works a little something like this:

```
What is V? V
V is .
What is V? _
```

This is by far the most insignificant little error I've ever come across. I swear I'm gonna go crazy if I don't figure this out..!

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning - Don't hurt your head with your face palm :-)

You have an extra space in your SET /P assignment. The name of the variable you are creating is 
`"V "` (quotes not included)

Remove the offending space before the `=` and all will be right in the world.

Comment: ... Thank you, you saved my sanity. XD I still can't believe that a space is the problem. Just goes to show ya how the tiniest little detail can be fatal in these kinds of things.

Comment: @VDgames - If this answered your question to your satisfaction, then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted for a given question. Once you reach 15 rep points you will gain the privilege to up vote any answer you find useful, including answers to other people's questions. Up votes award the answer poster 10 points.